# ImportError for skbio module

Tags: python, importerror, skbio

I am running Python 3 and have **skbio** v0.5.5 installed. Following the examples in [this tutorial](http://readiab.org/book/0.1.1/1/1), I am trying to run the import statements for some skbio classes, but am getting errors. For example,

```
from skbio.alignment import Alignment
```

results in

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Alignment' from 'skbio.alignment'

Also,

```
from skbio import BiologicalSequence
```

results in

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Alignment' from 'BiologicalSequence'

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What version of skbio are you using? These don't seem to exist in the latest version.

Comment: I am using the skbio version of 0.5.5. But in this tutorial http://readiab.org/book/0.1.1/1/1, you will see they are seeming to running these modules.

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer if it helped to solve your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Alignment` class is from an older version of the `skbio` library, specifically from before version 0.3.

If you would like to use those classes, you would need to install scikit-bio from before that version, by doing something like:

```
pip install scikit-bio==0.2
```

If you're just going through the Introduction to Applied Bioinformatics book, like you mentioned in your comment, it's better to [use the latest version of the book instead](http://readiab.org/book/latest/1/1), which will use the latest version of the scikit-bio library.

Comment: Thank you very much @Clarence Leung